# DyGraph with an independent series

Tags: angularjs-directive, dygraphs, bigdata

I start to use dygraph and I found some difficulties to work with independant series, specially because I have a voluminous data, is there any solution to work with independent series without formating data to especial format recommended by dygraph?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Google DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?csw=1#DataTable) to manage large data series.